# Redshift - Excel PowerPivot

Tags: excel, amazon-redshift, powerpivot

My goal is to import a table residing in Amazon redshift into powerpivot. It has 2M records.
I get the 'out of memory for query result' error when I attempt with the ODBC connection with redshift.

I tried to unload to the S3 bucket as a gzip file. The unload command itself took 1 min and created a 311MB .gz file. When I attempted to download the file to my local machine, it took 1 and 1/2 hours.
I don't have that much time.  What are my options ?

I have done this with SQL Server which was so much faster.

Comment: Download speed from S3 should be mostly depending on your connection, are you sure that it isn't the limiting factor?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. the speed was in kbps. I had to change the destination to a different machine to get better speed.